# '\' character in CN after user insertion through powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

First of all, I'm still a newbie and learning new things.
That said, I was asked to create thousands of users into the Active Directory, so I scoured the internet and found this script that imports a CSV file and for each line creates a new user.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\ADtest\User.csv"            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
{            
    $Displayname = $User.FirstName + " " + $User.Lastname            
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname            
    $UserLastname = $User.Lastname            
    $OU = $User.OU           
    $SAM = $User.SAM            
    $UPN = $User.Firstname + $User.Lastname + "@" + $User.MailDomain            
    $Description = $User.Description            
    $Password = $User.Password       
    New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $UserFirstname -Surname $UserLastname -Description $Description -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false –PasswordNeverExpires $true
    Write-Host $User.SAM "created successfully"
}
```

Used it and worked fine, but after executing a `dsquery` we noticed that the CN came out with a "\ " appended at the end of every each one of them, like so: `"CN=testuser000001\ ,OU=Users &Clients,OU=RM950D001,OU=DRZITA0001,DC=testad,DC=local"`

The input CSV file used to execute the script looks like the following

```
FirstName;LastName;SAM;OU;Password;MailDomain;Description
testuser000001;;testuser000001;OU=Users & Clients,OU=RM950D001,OU=DRZITA0001,DC=testad,DC=local;Password01;testad.local;
```

I've tried to run again manually the script by executing the instruction in the powershell console and was able to insert users without the appended backslash and space. So my wild guess is that Powershell when interpreting the script instruction appends those characters.

Please note that this charaters doesn't show in the "Active Directory Users and Computers" software.

Does someone have any idea as to why this could've happened?

Comment: Your hyperlink is the script itself. Can you [edit] you post to put the script content in there properly?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got the commands all mixed up

Comment: use `Trim()` on both the FirstName and the LastName. The `\` indicates the last character is a space and should therefore be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Theo mentioned, the last character in the CN is a space. The slash is simply a way to escape the space.

The CN comes from the `-Name` parameter, which you've set to `$Displayname`.

The space is there because of this:

```
$Displayname = $User.FirstName + " " + $User.Lastname
```

If there is no last name, it will append a space, then nothing. So you end up with a space at the end. A similar thing could happen if you have no first name: you'd end up with the last name preceded by a space.

An easy solution it to just trim the resulting string:

```
$Displayname = ($User.FirstName + " " + $User.Lastname).Trim()
```